# Why Hibernate executes SELECT query on lazy relationship attribute field

Tags: java, sql-server, spring, hibernate, spring-data-jpa

In my application, I have the following `@Entity`.

```
@Entity(name="DemoAccount")
@Table(name="staff")
@Getter @Setter @FieldNameConstants
@NoArgsConstructor
public class Account {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    protected Long id;
    @Column(name="username", nullable=false)
    private String userId;
    private String name;

    @ManyToOne(fetch=FetchType.LAZY)
    @LazyToOne(LazyToOneOption.NO_PROXY)
    @LazyGroup("nationality")
    @JoinColumn(name="nationality", referencedColumnName="code")
    private Nationality nationality;
}
```

I used Hibernate Bytecode Enhancer to define to-one relationship fields. When I execute my JPQL method to eagerly fetch the lazy fields, I'm seeing Hibernate execute all the joins properly.

```
2020-05-24 16:18:26,492 DEBUG [http-nio-9000-exec-1] org.hibernate.SQL   : 
    /* select
        generatedAlias0 
    from
        DemoAccount as generatedAlias0 
    where
        generatedAlias0.userId=:param0 */ select
            account0_.id as id1_61_0_,
            nationalit1_.id as id1_35_1_,
            account0_.name as name4_61_0_,
            account0_.username as username6_61_0_,
            nationalit1_.code as code2_35_1_,
            nationalit1_.name as name4_35_1_
        from
            staff account0_ 
        left outer join
            nationality nationalit1_ 
                on account0_.nationality=nationalit1_.code 
        where
            account0_.username=?
2020-05-24 16:18:26,492 TRACE [http-nio-9000-exec-1] org.hibernate.type.descriptor.sql.BasicBinder   : binding parameter [1] as [VARCHAR] - [90000010]
```

However, whenever I call `account.getNationality().getName()`, I always see the following select statement.

```
2020-05-24 16:18:26,506 DEBUG [http-nio-9000-exec-1] org.hibernate.SQL   : 
    /* sequential select
        com.ft.demo.db.customer.domain.Account */ select
            account_.nationality as nationa22_61_ 
        from
            staff account_ 
        where
            account_.id=?
2020-05-24 16:18:26,507 TRACE [http-nio-9000-exec-1] org.hibernate.type.descriptor.sql.BasicBinder   : binding parameter [1] as [BIGINT] - [660]
```

So if I have a list of 50 records, 50 additional select statements get executed. I'd be very grateful if you could tell me what I've done wrong.

FYI: I'm using the latest Spring Boot 2.2.7 and Hibernate is at 5.4.15.Final.

**UPDATE**:

Below is my Hibernate Bytecode Enhancer plugin configurations.

```
  <plugin>
    <groupId>org.hibernate.orm.tooling</groupId>
    <artifactId>hibernate-enhance-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>${hibernate.version}</version>
    <executions>
      <execution>
        <configuration>
          <failOnError>true</failOnError>
          <enableLazyInitialization>true</enableLazyInitialization>
        </configuration>
        <goals>
          <goal>enhance</goal>
        </goals>
      </execution>
    </executions>
  </plugin>
```

Comment: What hibernate version do you use?

Comment: @SternK From the `pom.xml` of Spring Boot 2.2.7, I'm seeing Hibernate is at version 5.4.15.Final. Are you suspecting a bug?

Comment: I faced with problems related to bytecode enhancement on hibernate 5.3 line. You use only `enableLazyInitialization` option, right?

Comment: @SternK: I updated the question with my current Hibernate Bytecode configuration in Maven :). Please let me know if you need any other information.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure to have `spring.jpa.open-in-view=false` in your `application.properties` file. If you have it set to true you will end up querying database when you call get method.